# thousands separator for a decimal field in a custom inputText component in Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a custom InputText control in blazor that works fine for text input but
If I bind it to a decimal field it doesn't work and I get an error for typecasting

here is my code:

this is my model

```
public class Quote
{
    [Required]     
    public string TotalQuoteCost { get; set; }
}
```

this is my Custom InputText

```
    @using System.Linq.Expressions


@inherits InputBase<string>


     <div class=@ColumnLocation>
          @if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Label))
            {              
                <label for="@Id">@Label</label>
            }                   
           <InputText @bind-Value="@CurrentValueAsString" class="form-control" placeholder="@Label"></InputText>
           <ValidationMessage For="@ValidationFor" />
     </div>

@code {

    [Parameter] public string Id { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string Label { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public Expression<Func<string>> ValidationFor { get; set; }



    protected override bool TryParseValueFromString(string value, out string result, out string validationErrorMessage)
    {
        decimal gg = decimal.Parse(value);
        result = String.Format("{0:n2}", gg); 
        validationErrorMessage = null;
        return true;
        }
 }
```

and this is the page:

```
@page "/counter"

   <EditForm Model="quote" OnValidSubmit="@SubmitButtonPressed" class="form-horizontal">
                    <DataAnnotationsValidator />

                     <UxInputText Label="Quote cost" @bind-Value="quote.TotalQuoteCost" 
                                               ValidationFor="@(() => quote.TotalQuoteCost)" 
                                               />

         <button type="submit" class="btn">Check 1</button>
         <h1>@ttt</h1>
   </EditForm>
@code {
    private string ttt = string.Empty;
    Quote quote = new Quote();
    protected void SubmitButtonPressed()
    {
        ttt = quote.TotalQuoteCost.ToString();
        }
}
```

If I define TotalQuoteCost as decimal **(it must be decimal )** I get this errors:

1- CS1662   Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type

2- CS1503   Argument 2: cannot convert from 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback'

3- CS0029   Cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal' to 'string'

Comment: Check this out. https://www.meziantou.net/bind-an-inputnumber-on-input-with-decimal-numbers-in-blazor.htm

Comment: [Polite] Question:  What's your objective.  Do you want to build a composite control containing  the label, input and validation messages?  If so there are simpler ways of achieving that than inheriting from `InputBase` for the wrapper.  Or do you want to show decimals with thousand separators?

Comment: I want to build a composite control, and I want to show "," (Thousand separators) with decimals, and also I want to add the label and validation as well. it works if I change the model field's type but I don't want to do it because It, not a good way to use string for currency in the database

Comment: @meziantou  please check this

Answer (score 0):

Main issue is your component inheriting InputBase of type string instead of InputNumber of type decimal:

```
@using System.Linq.Expressions

@inherits InputNumber<decimal>

<div class=@ColumnLocation>
    @if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Label))
    {              
        <label for="@Id">@Label</label>
    }                   

    <InputText @bind-Value="@CurrentValueAsString" class="form-control" placeholder="@Label"/>
    <ValidationMessage For="@ValidationFor" />
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public string Id { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string Label { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public Expression<Func<decimal>> ValidationFor { get; set; }

    protected override bool TryParseValueFromString(string value, out decimal result, out string validationErrorMessage)
    {
        result = decimal.Parse(value);
        validationErrorMessage = null;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then you can update your model:

```
public class Quote
{
    [Required]     
    public decimal TotalQuoteCost { get; set; }
}
```

And not sure I changed much for the page besides small edits:

```
<EditForm Model="quote" OnValidSubmit="@SubmitButtonPressed" class="form-horizontal">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />

    <UxInputText type="number" Label="Quote cost" @bind-Value="quote.TotalQuoteCost" ValidationFor="@(() => quote.TotalQuoteCost)" />   

    <button type="submit" class="btn">Check 1</button>
    <h1>@ttt</h1>
</EditForm>

@code {
    private string ttt = string.Empty;
    Quote quote = new();

    protected void SubmitButtonPressed()
    {
        ttt = quote.TotalQuoteCost.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I will say, although I didn't see it initially, I ended up using the same resource posted by @ChinmayT. So I'd refer be sure to give that a good look as well.

Comment: it doesn't work, because I want to add a "," (thousand separator) in the Input. in this case it doesn't show the separator

Comment: Use ".ToString("N")". This will add the separator for you.

Comment: Please note the "result" in your code is decimal and we can't use ToString("N")